# Creating an API for connecting MS SQL and MySQL databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I am trying to connect MS SQL and MySQL databases.
I tried to use Linked server...It creates an instance of MySQL databases in MS SQL. But what I need is a separate table from a database should connect both the servers.
I was using PHP to insert record to MySQL when I insert in MySQL. It should be automatically insert in to MS SQL  Server.

Please try to give some ideas...or any other better way.

Comment: You should say somethings what you tried.

Comment: You need to give some examples of what you tried, should try and do some research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger for this.

You must create a trigger inside of MYSQL. when a record added to MYSQL database, automatically add this row to the MSSQL.